# Tomcat dies suddenly

Tags: java, tomcat, crash, jvm

Trying to diagnose some bizarre Tomcat (`7.0.21`) and/or JVM errors on a 64-bit linux (CentOS) machine.

I'm load testing our server application and tried hitting it with 100K messages. Launched `jvisualvm` and kept my eye on the heap the whole time. Everything was looking great* (see below) until I got to about 93K processed messages and then Tomcat just died. Ran a `ps` on Tomcat's PID number to confirm it was dead.

Up until this crash:

- Load test had been running for about 90 minutes; should have finished shortly thereafter since we were at 93K/100K)
- CPU was holding strong around 45%
- Used heap was around 2GB (plus or minus a bunch after GCs) but heap size grew from 4GB to `MAX_HEAP` after about 30 minutes
- Class loading/unloading was cycling normally
- Thread dumps were normal

Nowhere in the server code are any calls to `System.exit()` - so we can rule that right out (and yes I've double-checked!!!).

I'm not sure if this is Tomcat crashing or the JVM (**how do I tell?**). And even if I did know, I can't seem to find any indication of what went wrong:

- All of the server app's logs just stop without any ERROR messages (even though we have logging universally set to DEBUG and higher)
- Tomcat's `catalina.out` and respect `localhost_access_*` files just stop without any info

I've heard it is possible to have Tomcat log a coredump when it does but not sure how to do that and online examples aren't helping much.

How would SO go about diagnosing this? What steps should I take to start ruling out all of the possible factors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it Schrödinger's tomcat?

Comment: Did you check more logs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575730/debugging-tomcat-crash

Comment: FYI in my experience you can tell if tomcat is killed by the OOM Killer as the word 'Killed' will appear somewhere close to the end of catalina.out.

Comment: Try to add a swapfile to your system. It doesn't have to be big. https://superuser.com/questions/1445510/how-do-i-run-xwiki-in-centos7-with-1gb-ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I had to remove the green check from @erickson. I finally figured out what was killing Tomcat.

It looks like a profiler plugin is not configured correctly with VisualVM and attempting to run a profile on the Tomcat process killed it.

Investigating why right now, and will update this answer once I know more.

Comment: You mean, "it's also possible that `jvisualvm` is causing the crash?" ;)

Comment: Shouldn't you only accept the answer when you know all the details?

Answer (score 15):

If the JVM crashes, you should have a hs_err_pidNNN.log file; you don't have to do anything to enable this. Its location depends on your OS and how you are running Tomcat. On Windows, they can show up on your desktop, unless you are running as a service. Otherwise, they should be in the current working directory of the crashed process.

Your operating system probably provides additional tools for process monitoring; you could describe your environment more, or perhaps ask at [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/).

It's also possible that `jvisualvm` is actually causing the crash.

I'd try reproducing the problem, and progressively simplify the scenario to help isolate the cause.

Comment: Thanks erickson, where would I find this log file? I assume in my JDK directory or thereabouts?

Comment: ahhh nm - looks like it will either be the cwd or /tmp

Comment: It depends on your OS and how you are running Tomcat. On Windows, they can show up on your desktop, unless you are running as a service. Otherwise, they should be in the current working directory of the crashed process.

Comment: One last question - how could jvisualvm be causing the crash? By eating up too much memory? How could I diagnose this?

Comment: I don't have a specific mechanism in mind for `jvisualvm`, it's just one more variable that you can toggle.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  My tomcat is crashing with no logs..  I am using CentOs 6.2.  I Checked hs_err_pid, I dont have any logs on it.  Also there is no JVM crash found in my logs.  I have also looked for OOM killer logs also.  can you please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: Sorry for downvote. I clicked it by mistake :( I can't get back

Comment: What if it runs as a system process with `systemctl start tomcat`?

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is that the OS is running out of memory and the [OOM Killer](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2009/09/30/how-the-linux-oom-killer-works/) is killing your process. In this case, the JVM wouldn't get an opportunity to write a heap dump, or an hs_err_pid file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the option java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to create a heap dump for jvm crash due to out of memory error.

More details here [Using HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError parameter for heap dump for JBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542979/using-heapdumponoutofmemoryerror-parameter-for-heap-dump-for-jboss).