# In My production System, running my web app in Tomcat 7 every two days tomcat has stopped automatically

Tags: java, tomcat7

In My production System, running my web application(java application) in Tomcat 7 every two days tomcat has stopped automatically.In Tomcat logs showing below error.

> Aug 08, 2013 2:30:17 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
>   clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [] is still
>   processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to
>   create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to
>   finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context
>   implementation.

Can any one please help me?

Comment: as logs suggest u have memory leaks in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I have notice some problem like that and it had been related to the OOM-Killer on linux-based systems. Take a look at at your system log.

Also, check this link:
[Tomcat dies suddenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132496/tomcat-dies-suddenly)

Comment: but i am using windows-based system

Comment: hum ... so I recommend you following this link in order to look at JVM crash logs, heap dump, and profiling your app.