# Tomcat shutsdown at load test

Tags: java, performance, spring-mvc, tomcat, ubuntu-12.04

On Ubuntu 12 server and Tomcat 7, I load test my spring mvc application for one specific REST get method. (using an online load test tool)

For 1 user per second and over a minute it works fine. But when I load test 50 users per second, after a short while tomcat shutsdown, so I have to restart it again. I checked logs but no error was there.

Where can I start to find the problem? Becoming slow, or unresponsive could be something that I could understand, but shuting down dont make sense.

Comment: Start with checking the tomcat logs. It might be in `/var/lib/tomcat7/logs` folder.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you are having issues under load testing. Anyway, check all the logs possible, also see if any heap dump is generated during the termination (look for `*.hprof` files under tomcats working directory)

Comment: Similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132496/tomcat-dies-suddenly